# keras activation function layer: model.add Activation('relu') gives invalid syntax error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Trying to build layer by following code and an error come out

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle","rb"))
X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3) , input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add((Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=1, validation_split=0.1)
```

please someone should help out. I use jupyter notebook in python 2.7 environment and the above code returns:

```
File "<ipython-input-37-f4c444b06108>", line 16
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why are you using brackets in the line `model.add((Conv2D(64, (3,3)))` , replace it with `model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))`

Comment: right, at least the same amount of closing brackets like opening brackets have to be in that line.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that the line ***above*** the reported line didn't end correctly. Notice that you have an extra parenthesis on line 15. ;)

```
model.add((Conv2D(64, (3,3))) # <--- 4 open, 3 closed
model.add(Activation("relu"))
```